# How do I do a page transition in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I want to use backbone to render a view? But I want the view to animately appear to the user. It should fade then scale just like the animation for Fade and Scale here:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Here's my code:

```
if (!this.firstUseOverlayView) {
    this.firstUseOverlayView = new NPWFirstUseView({
        isOverlay: true,
        el: '.first-use-overlay'
    });
}
this.firstUseOverlayView.render();
```

This renders the view into the main div. I want the view to transition (fade and scale) when it appears to the user. Please see link above. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that since the view gets added to the DOM dynamically, it's as easy as putting a CSS animation on it.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h442xbcy/1/) with a demo, and the relevant CSS is below (without vendor prefixes, for simplicity).

```
@keyframes imageFadeIn {
  0%{opacity:0; transform: scale(0.5)}
  100%{opacity:1; transform: scale(1)}
}
.first-use-overlay {
  animation:imageFadeIn 0.3s 1 ease-out;
}
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks. How do I copy the animation for the close? If you click on the Fade in & Scale button it has a "Close Me" button. How can I add that same effect when closing the view?

Comment: Closing animations are a little more complicated. I'm not strong enough with Backbone to say exactly how to do it in there, but the trick is to add a class to `.first-use-overlay`, like "closing" and a setTimeout for the length of the closing animation (which would just be the reverse of the one above). The key is not removing the view from the DOM until the animation has completed.

Comment: How can I do the above but use transitions instead?

Comment: I put together another JSFiddle using transitions instead: https://jsfiddle.net/jameson5555/h442xbcy/2/ This way is a little more complicated since you'd need to add a class to the overlay after Backbone adds it to the DOM for the transition to trigger off of.